# How to iterate js function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize, visualforce

I have some repeat button control functions as below, is there a way to iterate them and reduce amount of code?

```
    $('[id$=cBC1]').change(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".cBC1_Row").prop("disabled", true); 
      }
      else {
        $(".cBC1_Row").prop("disabled", false);
      }
      $('select').material_select();
    });

    $('[id$=cBC2]').change(function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".cBC2_Row").prop("disabled", true); 
      }
      else {
        $(".cBC2_Row").prop("disabled", false);
      }
      $('select').material_select();
    });

    ...
```

Add HTML code as requested, it's wrapped in a visualforce page, each checkbox will manage text fields on the same row in table.

```
      <table>
        ...
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <apex:inputCheckbox id="cBC1"/>
              <label for="j_id0:j_id1:cBC1"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="input-field">
                <apex:inputField styleClass="validate cBC1_Row"/>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="input-field">
                <apex:inputField styleClass="validate cBC1_Row"/>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <apex:inputCheckbox id="cBC2"/>
              <label for="j_id0:j_id1:cBC2"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="input-field">
                <apex:inputField styleClass="validate cBC2_Row"/>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="input-field inline">
                <apex:inputField styleClass="validate cBC2_Row"/>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: please add html too

Comment: Parameterize what's different, run the function for as many times as as there are different sets of params.

Comment: I bet your html can be simplified...

Answer (score 2):

You could drop the last number in the selector, and use "attribute contains" instead, assuming you don't have several elements containing the string `cBC`.
An other, and better option, would be to use classes

```
$('[id*=cBC]').on('change', function () {
    $(".cBC"+ this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0] +"_Row").prop("disabled", this.checked); 
    $('select').material_select();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, following your pattern you can do:

```
for (let i = 1; i < amoutOfIds; i++) {
  $('[id$=cBC'+i+']').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(".cBC"+i+"_Row").prop("disabled", true); 
    }
    else {
      $(".cBC"+i+"_Row").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    $('select').material_select();
  });
}
```

You have to set correctly the `amountOfIds` you have, and also you should be changing `let i = 1` also to begin with the first id you have.

Answer (score -1):

If you can refactor your event handler to work for each element, you could write a single jquery selector and bind the same anonymous event handler to both elements. It is difficult to determine whether or not this refactoring is feasible without seeing the markup of the elements your script is interacting with.

Answer (score -1):

From your code it seems the IDs are matched. 
Why not using:

```js
$('[id^="cBC"]').change(function () {
   var _id = $(this).id();
   $("."+_id+"_Row").prop("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
  $('select').material_select();
  });
```